# How do I remove 'Home' from homepage title?

Tags: title

On the site I am working on, currently page titles have this format:

```
Page title | Site name
```

This is fine, but I want the Page title removed from the homepage, as the Google search result for the homepage has 'Home' in it.

So how do I change the title for just the homepage, from...

```
Home | Site name
```

to..

```
Site name
```

?

This is the relevant part in `header.php`:

```
<title><?php


        global $page, $paged;

        wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );

        // Add the blog name.
        bloginfo( 'name' );

        // Add the blog description for the home/front page.
        $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
        if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
                echo " | $site_description";

        // Add a page number if necessary:
        if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
                echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'twentyeleven' ), max( $paged, $page ) );

        ?></title>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a check to see if the current page is the home page, and if so skip adding the page title. This would make the final code look like this:

```
<title><?php

global $page, $paged;

// Add the page title if not the front page
if ( is_front_page() ) {
        wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );
}

// Add the blog name.
bloginfo( 'name' );

// Add the blog description for the home/front page.
$site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
        echo " | $site_description";

// Add a page number if necessary:
if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
        echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'twentyeleven' ), max( $paged, $page ) );

?></title>
```

---

However, the best thing to do would be to use this code in `header.php`:

```
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
```

And then filter the title using this code in `functions.php`:

```
function wpse_132052_wp_title( $title, $sep ) {
    global $paged, $page;

    // Add the blog name
    $title .= get_bloginfo( 'name' );

    // Use the site name and description for the home/front page
    if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) {
        $title = get_bloginfo( 'name' );

        // Add the site description for the home/front page.
        $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
        if ( $site_description && (  ) ) {
                $title = "$title $sep $site_description";
        }
    }

    // Add a page number if necessary:
    if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2  ) {
        echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'twentyeleven' ), max( $paged, $page ) );
    }

    return $title;

}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'wpse_132052_wp_title', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: @paradroid check if force rewrite titles setting is enabled on the Titles & Metas SEO menu. If it is, disable it

Comment: I also needed to remove `bloginfo( 'name' );` to stop duplicate site names.

Comment: @paradroid try using the new code in the answer. It's the correct method for handling page titles, and should fix any errors with the site title